# name of a movie where a giant octopuslike creature climbs a lighthouse

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, h-p-lovecraft

I was just a little kid, so my memories are scarse. But here are the facts:

1 - It was no animation. It had real people.

2 - It was in color. Maybe 70s or early 80s.

3 - Maybe BBC.

4 - The story, as I remember it, was set in the 18<sup>th</sup> or 19<sup>th</sup> centuries. Could have been Victorian style.

5 - I think is H. P. Lovecraft or Edgar Allan Poe inspired.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you are remembering the Doctor Who episode [*The Horror of Fang Rock*](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Horror_of_Fang_Rock_(TV_story)), in which a green jellyfish-like alien called a [Rutan](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Rutan_Host) climbed a lighthouse, as shown in the screenshot on [this page](http://www.cdogzilla.net/2013/05/horror-of-fang-rock-dont-fire-until-you.html):

[image]

It aired on BBC in 1977, was live-action and in color, and was set around 1900, so it matches your criteria 1-4 (not sure if it was directly Lovecraft or Poe inspired but it had that sort of style).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Not 100% sure it is the right thing but it certainly could be. if someone else has another suggestion, i'll be glad to hear it. Until that point i'll mark your answer as the right one. thanks.